# Probability.....

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

There are $65$ currency notes of RS $1000$ and $35$ currency notes of RS $500$ in a safe. If $4$ notes are selected randomly find that total amount obtained is at least Rs $4000$

It's answer is $0.1727$ 
The method I tried is $1-($total amount is not $4000)$ but couldn't get the desired answer.

Comment: Please use a more informative title for your question next time.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $4000=4 \times 1000$ so in this case *at least* $4000$ is equivalent to *exactly* $4000$
- you do not need to subtract from $1$
- you do need to take account of sampling *without* replacement

Comment: So I'm supposed to do 1/65+1/65+1/65+1/65 ?

Comment: No - the first note selected must be $1000$ *and then* the second note selected must be $1000$ *and then* ... . Work out the probabilities of each event conditional on the previous ones and combine appropriately

Comment: @AYESHA Not exactly. What you wrote would be sampling _with_ replacement. But once you take out a RS 1000 note you have only 64 of those notes remaining that could be taken next.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get RS $4000$ with four notes is to pick out four RS $1000$ notes.

So choose $4$ of the $65$ RS $1000$ notes (how many ways?) and divide by the total number of ways you can choose four notes (how many ways?)

Spoiler:

> ${65 \choose 4} / {100 \choose 4}$